# Identify this waterfowl species?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I've been unable to find anything on the Google resembling this bird. I took the photo in Virginia Beach, VA around 2010, October, I think...
It appears to be between winter and summer plumage but I'm not sure. I tried looking on whatbird.com but couldn't find anything that really seemed to match up well.

**Edit**

I've added some more photos since people seem to question whether or not the white is snow, for some reason. Also note that most seem to have a red bill with a black tip, while the one with more white on its breast has a largely black bill with just a red band. Do bills change colors when plumage does, is that a thing, or perhaps it's just an anomaly or a gender trait?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's seasonal plumage change going on here.  The white patches seem to be driven snow.  The bird on the left is plastered like the tree on the right.

Comment: There is snow, but it's not all snow. Also notice that the bills are two different colors.

Comment: It looks like a male and a female with the female being smaller and read beaked.

Comment: They don't really look like different sizes to me(at least, not drastic enough that I'd think it was a gender distinction...) the one on the left just has its head up and the one on the right has its head down.

Comment: Yes, looks like *Cairina Moschata* - Muscovy Duck. Native to Americas, domestic/semi-wild in Europe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not an ornithologist, but using identify.whatbird.com and a simple google search, this appears to be a Muscovy Duck. Try a google image search for yourself! Some of the birds pictured have more ostentatiously red or larger caruncles, but some look very similar to the birds you photographed. For example: http://www.birdinginformation.com/birds/ducks/muskovy-duck/

From muscovyduckcentral.com and identify.whatbird.com:
The domestic breeds can come in a variety of colors, but are primarily black and white with red and white bills. The males are larger than the females -- around 15 lbs for a male and only 8 lbs for a female. Females are duller colored than the males. Muscovy ducks are indigenous to Mexico, Central and South America, but are now raised in many different locations. They are considered a good duck stock because they are large, breed quickly, provide good pest control, and are quieter than many other duck breeds.

Comment: I used whatbird.com for VA and that didn't come up ... (as mentioned in my comments) Well, your google-fu is obviously superior to mine. Thanks :D

Comment: Aaaah, that'd be why it dodn't show up in VA. I would've thought it would take migration into account tho. Huh.